# Do I need to Implement REST to Authenciate Users to a PHP webservice

Tags: android, web-services, rest, authentication, post

Im creating a simple Android Application,which requires reading and writing values to the cloud.I intent to use PHP for the webservice.But im little confused over the authentication scheme.I intent to host a script `www.mycoolsite.com/magic.php` and POST data to it from Android.

Here are my questions

1.Will there be a problem if large number of users at the same time use the script.There will be different Tables for Different Users?Should i worry about concurrency?

2.Do i need some API Like REST? Can i send the username and password(encrypted) in POST to Authenticate and Identify the user?The data send needs to be encrypted anyways,will this be a bottleneck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the Rest based WEB API, and pass the log in credential in the JSON and then check in your WEB API whether user is authenticated. It does not create any bottleneck like that.

Comment: Is sending the username and password in JSON Object secure?

Comment: You can send those in the encrypted form

Comment: Is there a need for SSL?

Comment: Not much required, it would be best if you go through that

Comment: Okay.I think most android applications will be working like this.Im new to this.